# Do you know any graphing software for graphing equipotential lines?

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, software

well, do you know any software for graphing equipotential lines? I only know how to graph straight lines :( Thanks for any information.

Comment: Equipotential lines are known as contours in the plotting community, and every plotting package out there should be able to make a contour plot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a software recommendation, not physics.

Answer (score 1):

You can try gnuplot, it might have a slight learning curve at the beginning, but overall it's very versatile:

http://www.gnuplotting.org/equipotential-lines/

http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_canvas/vector.html